# Integer to string conversion function in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a number as follows: 
13901210
I want the output to give the following result
1390/12/10

Input function: a number of bigint
Output: a string

How do I create this function?

Answer (score 4):

I wonder why no one suggested this Simple Query

```
declare @input bigint=13901210

select REPLACE(Convert(varchar,Convert(date,CONVERT(varchar,@input))),'-','/')
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/13941)**

Comment: will this depend on culture info?

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @integer int = 13901210;
DECLARE @part1 int = @integer / 10000;
DECLARE @part2 int = (@integer - @integer / 10000 * 10000) / 100;
DECLARE @part3 int = @integer - @integer / 100 * 100;

DECLARE @result char(10) =
   CAST(@part1 AS char(4)) + '/'
 + CAST(@part2 AS char(2)) + '/'
 + CAST(@part3 AS char(2))

SELECT Part1 = @part1, Part2 = @part2, Part3 = @part3, Result = @result;
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(CAST(13901210 AS varchar(8)), 1,4) + '/' + SUBSTRING(CAST(13901210 AS varchar(8)), 5,2) + '/' + SUBSTRING(CAST(13901210 AS varchar(8)), 7,2)
```

Just replace the value with whatever field/variable you have with the number stored

The full function would look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[int_to_slashed_string] ( @value int )
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
DECLARE @string varchar(8);
SET @string = CAST(@value AS varchar(8));
RETURN SUBSTRING(@string, 1,4)
    + '/' + SUBSTRING(@string, 5,2)
    + '/' + SUBSTRING(@string, 7,2);
END
```

This function assumes the value contains 8 digits. If there are other limitations or conditions, the function will have to be modified.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to substring the value then you can do this:

```
DECLARE @nbr INT=13901210
SELECT 
    LEFT(@nbr,4)+'/'+
    SUBSTRING(CAST(@nbr AS VARCHAR(10)),5,2)+'/'+
    RIGHT(@nbr,2)
```

And then the function would look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetDateFormatForInt] (@nbr int)
RETURNS varchar(10)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN
    LEFT(@nbr,4)+'/'+
    SUBSTRING(CAST(@nbr AS VARCHAR(10)),5,2)+'/'+
    RIGHT(@nbr,2);
END
```

This will only work if is a 10 digit number

Answer (score 0):

This also works for me:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE getdatestr
    @result nvarchar(12) output,
    @info bigint 
    AS
    BEGIN
    SET @result=(SELECT LEFT(CAST(@info AS VARCHAR(8)),4)+'/'+
    SUBSTRING(CAST(@info AS VARCHAR(8)),5,2)+'/'+
    RIGHT(CAST(@info AS VARCHAR(8)),2))
    RETURN @result
    END
    GO
```

Except that LEFT,RIGHT return nvarchar and SUBSTRING returns string :) Anyways try it...it gives the same output and if you are ok with it then it is simple to get.